# How to do for return in main with pointer to pointer to pointer?

Tags: c, arguments, program-entry-point, free, void

```
void    ft_destroy(char ***factory);

int     main()
{
    char name[] = "sebastian";
    char *pt1 = &name;
    char **pt2 = &pt1;
    char ***pt3 = &pt2;
    printf("%s", ft_destroy(pt3));
    return (0);
}
```

```
error: incompatible pointer types initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'char (*)[10]'
      [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        char *pt1 = &name;
```

Comment: You need `char *pt1 = name;` and even better : `const char *pt1 = name;`

Comment: And when you fix that, `printf("%s", ft_destroy(pt3));` is broken, too.  How do you expect the string format specifier to work on the result of a void function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is an array of 10 `char`, which is a `char [10]`. So `&name` is a pointer to an array of `char`, which is a `char (*)[10]`. Since `pt1` is a `char *`, you should assign to it a pointer to a `char`.

Since `name` is an array of `char`, `name[0]` is a `char`, and `&name[0]` is a pointer to a `char`. So you can do `char *pt1 = &name[0];`.

If you just use `name`, C will automatically convert it to a pointer to its first element, so you can also do `char *ptr1 = name;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *pt1 = &name;
```

`&name` is address of type `char[10]` you need `char (*pt1)[10]` to store it.

Perhaps you can do as below.

```
char *pt1 = &name[0]; //or char *pt1 = name;
```

in this case `&name[0]` is of type `char *`.